# How can I create sub-domains in my hosting plan using asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-hosting

As I said above, I need to make asp create subdomains.

For example, I have a sign up page and I want for every user to have his own subdomain (profile).

And I need to make it automatically.

- I'm using asp.net mvc (Framework)
- hostgator personal windows plan

`I didn't try anything yet so I don't have a code`

Is it possible ?

[image: Example picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's only possible for internal AD network.  You could use c# to run Powershell command line to register CNAME in DNS and IIS. So that every user would have a private sub-domain name.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/?view=winserver2012-ps&redirectedfrom=MSDN

However, I think that's impossible to do the samething for public domain name since hostgator seems to a virtual machine toward public network.